# Mostrar con php la diferencia en horas yminutos entre dos campos datetime de mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes a todos,

Tengo un sistema donde debo controlar la hora de entrada y salida de vehículos. Para ello tengo almacenado en Mysql dos campos tipo DateTime (fecha1, fecha2). Necesito, en PHP, calcular la diferencia entre ambos campos y mostrarlo horas y minutos y segundos, sabiendo que fecha1 es la hora de entrada y fecha2 la de salida. De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que has investigado hasta ahora? MySQL tiene funciones ya incluídas para diferencia de fechas, puedes regresarle ese dato a PHP y ya tu procesarlo a como requieras mostrarlo en tu aplicación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Has probado con la clase [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)?

Te permite comparar dos fechas y te regresa un objeto de tipo DateInterval.

[Ejemplo:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905174/calculate-the-difference-between-2-timestamps-in-php)

```
// Traducción del ejemplo del usuario Learner (publicado: Dec 1, 2016)
// Post Original: "calculate the difference between 2 timestamps in php";
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905174/calculate-the-difference-between-2-timestamps-in-php

$fecha1 = new DateTime('2016-11-30 03:55:06');//fecha inicial
$fecha2 = new DateTime('2016-11-30 11:55:06');//fecha de cierre

$intervalo = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);

echo $intervalo->format('%Y años %m meses %d days %H horas %i minutos 
%s segundos');//00 años 0 meses 0 días 08 horas 0 minutos 0 segundos
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta...voy a implementarlo.

Comment: Recuerda, que el objeto DateInterval tiene un campo llamado Invert, el cual te indica si la diferencia es positiva o negativa (0 positiva, 1 negativa). Quizas debas implementar en el formato el %R (para mostrar si es negativo o positivo). Analiza tu caso

Answer (score 2):

Excelente me ayudo mucho.

Si estas usando laravel (mi caso) para calcular las fechas es practicamente lo mismo solo que incluye `DATETIME` después de tu `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

```
use DateTime;
```

Ya puedes usarlo en tu controlador. Esto es útil cuando quieres saber cuanto tiempo tarda en ejecutarse una función si es que estas haciendo proceso de importaciones o análisis complejos.

```
$fecha1 = new DateTime();//fecha inicial

/*
*Aquí pones tu código o anidación de funciones.
*/

$fecha2 = new DateTime();//fecha de cierre
$intervalo = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
echo ' Tiempo de ejecución: '.$intervalo->format('%i minutos %s segundos');
```

El `echo` lo desvuelves en la petición [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) como la respuesta lo imprimes en algún modal y listo se ve coqueto.