# moldear resultado entre resta de dos fechas

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente excel donde debo restar la fecha menor y mayor encontrada en un LOOP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ejemplo obtengo de resultado 1,67.

En PHP tengo la siguiente formula para calcular la diferencia entre las dos fechas.

```
$min_date = '2020-04-22 15:30:00';
$max_date = '2020-04-24 07:30:00';

$dif_min       = new DateTime($min_date);
$dif_max       = new DateTime($max_date);

$intervalo = $dif_min->diff($dif_max);

$horas_totales = $intervalo->format('%d:%H:%i');
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente resultado `1:16:0`, **alguna forma de llegar o moldear el resultado como el del excel.**

Espero poder haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Te refieres a añadir los días, mes y año? Si es así solo tienes que indicarlos en el ->format('%y-%M-%d %H:%i');

Comment: @Jakala verdad, pero tengo de resultado `1.16`

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres obtener exactamente? ¿La diferencia en horas entre las dos fechas? No entiendo a qué equivaldría el `1,67` Entre las dos fechas hay una diferencia de 1 dia y 16 horas. Eso, llevado a un valor de `1,16` ¿qué significa exactamente para tus propósitos?

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola, la idea mia es poder llegar al mismo resultado que el excel. 
El `1,67` es una resta en excel entre dos fechas.

Comment: El dato que al parecer quieres se obtendría así: `$horas_totales = $intervalo->format('%d,%H');` de todos modos, dado que no explicas la premisa, sigo sin entender qué sentido tiene o qué comportamiento o valor se espera en el caso de que haya diferencia también con respecto a los segundos por ejemplo, o si hay diferencias también con respecto a los meses y/o años entre ambas fechas...

Comment: Lo que sucede es que excel te devuelve el resultado en DIAS y PHP te lo esta devolviendo en dias y horas, por ejemplo, PHP te dice que son 1:16 porque es un dia con 16 horas, excel dice 1.67 porque es un dia con el 67% del otro (16/24), el resultado es el mismo, la presentación no, si quieres el 67 solo divide las horas entre 24

Comment: @JosueArriola debo sacar las horas primeros dividirlas x 24 y luego agregarle los dias?

Comment: Bien visto @JosueArriola. Aplicando lo que José sugiere, simplemente con esto lo obtendrías: `$horas_totales=$intervalo->d+round($intervalo->h/24, 2);`  ahora bien, cuando se resuelve un problema, hay que contar con otros factores, como te comenté antes: **¿qué debe ocurrir en el caso de que haya diferencias con respecto a los años, meses, segundos...?** Creo que debes exponer claramente el problema para obtener una solución global, no parcial, que, no arrojará el resultado esperado en esos casos. Casi siempre es mejor trabajar con la totalidad del tiempo y luego formatear según la necesidad.

Comment: Lo que esta en esta respuesta no te sirve? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95035/mostrar-con-php-la-diferencia-en-horas-yminutos-entre-dos-campos-datetime-de-mys

Answer (score 0):

Esa diferencia es en días y el proceso es bastante sencillo:

1- `$intervalo` tiene propiedades publicas para almacenar año (y), mes (m), días (d), etc.
2- Tomas los días
3- Tomas las horas y divides entre 24

```
$min_date = '2020-04-22 15:30:00';
$max_date = '2020-04-24 07:30:00';

$dif_min       = new DateTime($min_date);
$dif_max       = new DateTime($max_date);

$intervalo = $dif_min->diff($dif_max);

$dias = $intervalo->d + round($intervalo->h / 24, 2);
echo $dias;
```

> Resultado: 1.67

Si la diferencia involucra meses vas a tener que buscar otra alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado con la clase DateInterval?

Te permite comparar dos fechas y te regresa un objeto de tipo DateInterval.

```
// Traducción del ejemplo del usuario Learner (publicado: Dec 1, 2016)
// Post Original: "calculate the difference between 2 timestamps in php";
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905174/calculate-the-difference- 
between-2-timestamps-in-php

$fecha1 = new DateTime('2016-11-30 03:55:06');//fecha inicial
$fecha2 = new DateTime('2016-11-30 11:55:06');//fecha de cierre

$intervalo = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);

echo $intervalo->format('%Y años %m meses %d days %H horas %i minutos %s segundos');//00 años 0 meses 0 días 08 horas 0 minutos 0 segundos
```